# ionic 1 - add custom icon to nav button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-v1

i'd like to add an image as an icon to a navigation button in the header. is this possible? how should i go about it? here is my current code.. it doesnt work:

in the html code:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive custom-dark">
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button class="button" style="background: #1e1e1c;" ng-click="doSomething()">
  <i class="icon home"></i>
</button>
```

in the css code:

```
.home
{
  background: #1e1e1c;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image:  url('img/finalimages/home.png');
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom icon which can be put as your default back button alternative in ionic.

By doing this way you are getting a number of custom icons which can be used throughout your project.

This can be made by following this tutorial:[here](https://yannbraga.com/2017/06/28/how-to-use-custom-icons-on-ionic-3/)